# Is it possible to get the Creation order/Insertion order of elements in a TCL array?

Tags: tcl, associative-array

Tcl arrays are great for look up tables, but they are stored as "unordered sets" in theory.  Is there anyway to iterate thru them in the order elements were added to the array without adding extra code to track the insertion order yourself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is not way to get elements from an array back in the order they were added without keeping track of the insertion order yourself. The best way to get the behaviour you want is to move to using a **dictionary** rather than an array.  a dict does retain the order of insertions and as an aded bonus they are much nicer to work with when your passing them into or out of procs.

Comment: This is one of those cases where the Tcl documentation is somewhat lacking. I can't find any way that you could do this, but it would be nice if the doc for 'array' said that the order was implementation dependent or something. At any rate, your answer matches my experience with arrays.

Comment: +1: The implementation of hash tables used by arrays does not maintain order at all, and the details are sufficiently complex that “randomly reorders” is a much simpler explanation. Dicts are indeed the replacement, and they _specifically_ maintain insertion order; it's guaranteed.